# Matching the character before a linebreak, excluding whitespaces?

Tags: regex

So I currently have a regex (https://regex101.com/r/zBE4Ju/1) that highlights the words before and after a linebreak. This is nice, but the issue is sometimes there are whitespaces after the word that appears BEFORE the line break. So they end up

You can see on my regex101 how the issue happens, and I have outlined the problem. I need to recognize the word before and after the line break, regardless of if there is a space after the word.

```
(\w*(?:[\n](?![\n])\w*)+)
```

You can see it in action here https://regex101.com/r/zBE4Ju/3

Expected: Line 1
Actual: Line 3

Comment: Try `\w+(?:[^\S\r\n]*\r?\n\w+)+`, see https://regex101.com/r/zBE4Ju/5

Comment: You might use `^ *(?:\S+ +)*(\S+) *\r?\n` https://regex101.com/r/g4jVnb/1 to get those matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$1` from:

```
/([^ ]+) *(\r|\n)/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/o87VP7/5

Comment: This works, but I need to be able to accomodate words that have periods attached

Comment: @Andrew See the update. Instead of using `\w+`, `[^ ]+` will be much more inclusive.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up replacing \w+ with \S+

Comment: @Andrew Sure, that works too. Feel free to mark my answer as "accepted" if it helped you the most.

Comment: Done. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If you want to highlight the last "word" in the sentence followed by possible spaces and a newline, you could repeat 0+ times a group matching 1+ non whitespace chars followed by 1+ spaces.

Then capture in a group matching non whitespace chars `(\S+)` and match possible spaces followed by a newline.

```
^ *(?:\S+ +)*(\S+) *\r?\n
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `*` Match 0+ times a space
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\S+ +` Match 1+ non whitespace chars and 1+ spaces
    -`)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times (to also match a single word at the beginning)
- `(\S+)` Capture group 1, match 1+ times a non whitespace char
- `*\r?\n` Match 0+ times a space followed by a newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g4jVnb/1)